# Reference nth tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm trying to get a reference to the nth tab and dynamically show / hide said content based on the tab you click. It's easier to show what I have first:

```html
//Creating Tabs
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: ObjectToIterate -->
    <li><a data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'tab' + $index()}
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>

//Content To Show Based On Selected Tab
<!-- ko foreach: ObjectToIterate -->
    <div class="hidden" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'object' + $index()}"></div>  //All Hidden By Default (I can make the first one show later)
<!-- /ko -->
```

This is all working fine. I'm getting the two lists and it's out putting a unique id for each of the items in the `ObjectToIterate[]` arrays.

I'm at a loss for the Javascript/jQuery part. I'm trying to connect the click interaction of the nth element on the tab with the nth object to show. I know how to call an element in jQuery with a static id, but not a dynamic id. I also don't know how I would tie that dynamic id click with the nth object to show.

I hope this makes sense. I really simplified the code to help it make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use jquery for the click callback, keep it clean with knockout:

DOM:

```
<!-- ko foreach: ObjectToIterate -->
    <li><a href="#" data-bind="attr: { 'id': 'tab' + $index() }, click: tabClicked"></a> </li>
<!-- /ko -->
```

ViewModel:

```
var tabViewModel = {
     tabClicked: function(tab) { alert('Tab: ' + tab + ' clicked!'); };
};
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply. I was requested to NOT use knockout if possible, hence the question, but I think you're right; knockout seems like the cleanest and easiest solution. Let me give this a shot and I'll report back soon. Thanks!

Comment: I can't imagine ANY reason why you wouldn't use knockout for the click binding if you are already using it for the collection binding... unless you want to completely get rid of knockout...

Comment: I agree with this solution. In knockout, you've being passed with a data object as a first argument (current item you clicked in an observable array) and an event object. It's much more handy than trying to pass additional data to jquery via dom. And it's data-driven way, while jquery will create a mess.